# Azure end of life

Tags: azure

I have requirement to check end of life for resources present under my azure subscription. This will help us to plan upgrades, license renewals. Could you please let me know how to get all resources with end of life dates and details.

Edit: I am looking for some REST APIs to get all resources with end dates, azure alert or any other solution.

Comment: Do you mean something like this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?products=azure

Comment: Actually I am checking if any azure resources which are in our azure subscription has any upcoming upgrades, license expirations or that particular resource is going to be deprecated. Currently we have around 10+ subscriptions and many Azure resources are in it.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/products/?products=azure) provided by @Amr Elgarhy should be what you want. If you want to get all resources with end of life dates and detailed information, you only need to search the product and service list here, and then select the result to find support and service timelines, required updates, migration information, and system requirements.